# How to avoid ambiguity in "I am renting an apartment in New York"?

Tags: verbs, ambiguity

Does the sentence:

> I am renting an apartment in New York.

imply that I am the **landlord** or the **tenant**?

How can I unequivocally communicate that I am the tenant (or the landlord)?

Comment: *Rent* is an example of an [auto-antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym).

Comment: Complements aren't antonyms, are they?

Comment: In practice, outside of a landlord-related context, "rent" is almost always used in the tenant sense. It's probably safe to use it that way and only add clarification if you're using it in the landlord sense.

Comment: @octern: I don't know if that's an American perspective, but in British English, "to rent" (and indeed, "to hire") can describe both sides of the arrangement in a wide variety of contexts (vehicles, all manner of equipment, etc.). The sense becomes fixed if the verb is followed by "out" (only the owner can rent/hire *out*), but in practice the context invariably means there's no ambiguity anyway. In essence, both verbs often just mean *to be one of the two parties involved in a rental arrangement*.

Comment: The exact same word also is an auto-antonym in French: *Je loue un appartement à New-York* is ambiguous. The simplest way to clear the ambiguity is: *Je suis locataire d’un appartement…* means i'm tenant, *Je suis loueur d’un appartement* means I'm landlord.

Comment: Put this sentence in context and the meaning of "rent" will almost certainly become crystal clear.  "Where do you live?" "I rent an apartment in New York."  vs. "I rent an apartment in New York. I'm use the income to pay off my BMW."  Any sentence can be ambiguous (or even misleading) when taken in isolation, but perfectly clear when used in context. This phenomenon is not confined to the use of auto-antonyms. For example, is my BMW a car or a motorcycle? Did you even realize it was ambiguous?

Comment: This reminds me of *shoot*. You can shoot a gun, shoot a bullet, and shoot a target. You shot 3 things in one action!

Comment: It's exactly the same with the Spanish "alquilar".

Comment: @Russell Borogove is right, *rent* is more of a [polyseme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polysemes) than an  auto-antonym.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To "unequivocally communicate that I am the tenant (or the landlord)", among other things you could say one of the following.

> • As tenant, I rent an apartment...
>   • As landlord, I rent an apartment...

As previously noted by choster, adding *out* to original sentence works for *landlord* sense:

> I am renting out an apartment in New York.

You can state a not-landlord case, and perhaps imply tenancy, via

> I pay for renting an apartment in New York.

Comment: I think this answer is more complete than the others, so I am accepting it. It also summarizes what others have said, and provides two alternative answers to my second question.

Comment: May I pay you $500 a month to rent out your apartment to others for $1000 a month? In this case, "pay for renting [out] an apartment" would make sense.

Comment: @ErikE, re last line of answer, I agree it has the ambiguity you mention: there can be a landlord who owns an apartment and rents to a broker (the speaker) who in turn is landlord to actual tenant.  An ambiguity I contemplated but didn't mention is a landlord who says *pay for renting* and means *suffer anguish due to renting out*.

Answer (score 45):

As a renter I usually think of the tenant as *renting*, but the dictionaries seem to disagree with me as to primary use.

If you are the landlord, you could say

> I am renting out an apartment in New York.
>
> I have an apartment for rent in New York.
>
> I am letting an apartment in New York.

Comment: This helps, but it's not a complete solution. The tenant also needs a phrase that allows them to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @octern Despite the dictionary definition, colloquial usage is from the perspective of the tenant.  It's usually not considered ambiguous.

Comment: I agree, and upvoted your answer. But there are cases where it is genuinely ambiguous (e.g., poker night with your landlord pals), so having a way to disambiguate in both directions is still useful.

Comment: _I'm living in a rented apartment in New York._

Comment: *Letting* to me honestly doesn't seem to fix the problem. Can't a landlord *let* an apartment?

Comment: @ErikE when I read it, that's the meaning I thought was being implied as sole meaning.

Answer (score 12):

*Rent* is indeed ambiguous that way.

However, the two senses have different syntactic affordances.

- *I rented a house in Ypsilanti.* (ambiguous: Subject = tenant **or** owner)
- *I rented a house in Ypsilanti from him.* (unambiguous: Subject = tenant)
- *I rented a house in Ypsilanti to him.* (unambiguous: Subject = owner)
- *I rented him a house in Ypsilanti.* (unambiguous: Subject = owner)
- *I rented out a house in Ypsilanti.* (unambiguous: Subject = owner)

And there's lots of other ways to disambiguate them; in context, one is rarely confused.

Comment: +1 for that last sentence. The diametrically opposed meaning (which often also applies to *hire*) might look odd to non-native speakers, but in practice ambiguity is exceptionally unlikely.

Comment: Although, I might argue that the second to last sentence, "I rented him a house" could be interpreted as "I found and rented a house for him so that he had a place to stay while he was visiting."

Comment: Yes, benefactive _for_ phrases allow the Dative Alternation, i.e, _I rented a house for him_ <==> _I rented him a house_. **Provided** he winds up with the house; if I just filled in the papers in his stead and somebody else lives there, I rented the house for him, but I didn't rent him a house.

Comment: Can I use _I rented in.._ as a tenant? Or does it not make sense?

Comment: Yes, in that context, _rent_ contrasts with _own_, as two methods of securing shelter. However, _own_ requires an object, whereas _rent_ doesn't, at least not with subject tenant; landlord subject requires an object. _Q: Where do you live? A: I rent in Ypsilanti_ but not **I own in Ypsilanti*. Q: How do you make your living? A: **I rent in Ypsilanti*; that would have to be _I rent apartments/houses in Ypsilanti_.

Answer (score 7):

Tenant: I'm living in a rental apartment in New York.

Landlord: I'm renting out an apartment in New York.

Comment: You can rent an apartment without living in it, or indeed using it at all. It would probably be a pretty good way to get rid of some of one's cash to rent an apartment and not use it, but that's a different matter.

Comment: You can also live in a rental apartment without, yourself, renting it!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the [MW Dictionary entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rent?show=1&t=1342111959) for rent as a verb shows two entries:

> 1: to grant the possession and enjoyment of in exchange for rent
>
> 2: to take and hold under an agreement to pay rent

So the word officially can mean either.

I know that I personally would assume that if you "rent an apartment", then you are a tennant, but due to the ambiguity there's always room for doubt. But when in doubt, just add a clarification to your sentence.

One example: `I own an apartment for rent.`

Comment: Why is that "unfortunate"?  It's good to know that M-W lists both definitions; otherwise, it would be neither a useful nor accurate dictionary.

Comment: @J.R. Well said. The unfortunate was that it is perfectly ambiguous, but it is fortunate that's its accurate :)

Answer (score 4):

> Does the sentence: I am renting an apartment in New York. imply that I
>   am the landlord or the tenant?

If you use the word rent for both a landlord and a tenant then, that sentence is unclear.

> How can I unequivocally communicate that I am the tenant (or the
>   landlord)?

By use of the word let. As can be seen from the link here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/let_3, the word let unequivocally refers to a landlord. The word rent, normally refers to a tenant.

As a tenant, you can say "I am renting an apartment/flat (depending on which form of English you are speaking) in New York."

As a landlord, you can say "I am letting an apartment/flat (depending on which form of English you are speaking) in New York."

This would be the best way because, it is simple and unequivocal.

Comment: The catch to this is that the tenant side is still ambiguous to the reader. Unless you explain that you are only using "i am renting" in the "tenant direction", the reader has no way of knowing that. (I don't claim to have any answer better than adding more words to clarify.)

Comment: Although your link and sense 3 of *[let](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let)* at wiktionary both plainly mention *rent*, I'm still inclined to think of *let* as covering both rental and leasing.  I could be wrong.  I thought about mentioning *let* and *[lessor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lessor)* in my answer but supposed question distinguishes renting and leasing.

Comment: The tenant side does not have to remain ambiguous, if the word let is commonly used. This raises an important point. As long as certain people use the word rent to mean the landlord side as well, there will be ambiguity. People should really, distinguish this clearly by using the word let, more often. This would be the logical way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

> I am ***letting*** an apartment

or

> I have an apartment ***to let***

would imply that you are the landlord, or at least the letting agent. But certainly not the tenant.

Answer (score 3):

When I first read your question title, I had trouble figuring out the ambiguity -- I thought it had to do with whether your sought *apartment* is to be in New York, or whether *you* are in New York, looking for an apartment somewhere else.  :)

I found it quite unambiguous, since  I always thought **landlords *lease*** property, whereas **tenants *rent*** property.

I didn't think renting was ambiguous, in part because if someone were the landlord, he/she would probably write *lease* instead (e.g. leasing office).

Comment: Haven't heard of a leasing office, but (in the UK, at least), there are _letting agents_, who manage properties on behalf of landlords.

Answer (score 2):

The word is definitely ambiguous by itself. To be more explicit, I would expand the phrase:

> "I own an apartment(room/house/complex) that I am renting out in New York."

Answer (score 2):

For the owner, use "renting out", and be definite ("*my* apartment"):

> I am renting out my apartment in New York.

For the tenant, use "renting", and be indefinite ("*an* apartment):

> I am renting an apartment in New York.

With the slightest bit of context, I think these would be understood unambiguously.

Comment: "Renting out my apartment" gives me the impression of subletting to someone an apartment I'm renting from someone else.

Comment: I agree with jwpat7.  The singular *my apartment* carries the connotation that you are renting it from someone, not that you own it.  Probably because most landlords have *more* than one apartment for rent, and most rentees only rent one at a time.

Comment: @jwpat7 Could be, but I think New Yorkers know how to use "sublet" when they mean that.

Comment: @Daniel δ How could "renting *out*" mean that I am renting it from someone?

Comment: @talkaboutquality You can rent out what you are renting from someone.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the **verb to a phrase** with context to owner also works.

- change renting (v.) to "for rent" (n.)

I **need** an apt. "for rent" in NYC.

I **have** an apt. "for rent" in NYC.

I **have** an apt. "for sublet" in NYC that you may "rent".

... are unambiguous examples.
**edited apt. for appt.**

Comment: You may want to use "apt." to abbreviate apartment.  "appt." is generally short for appointment.

Comment: Why abbreviate at all? This isn't Twitter. (Also, why the scare quotes?)

Comment: @EvanM In NYC, even appointments are for rent :P

Answer (score 2):

"I am staying at a rented apartment" shows you are a tenant and "I have an apartment to let" shows you are the landlord.

Answer (score 2):

In UK English one would say:

1. I'm renting a flat [from xyz]. (I'm the tenant).
2. I'm renting out my flat [to xyz]. (I'm the owner).
3. I'm letting my flat from xyz. (I'm the tenant).
4. I'm letting my flat [to xyz]. (I'm the owner).

Answer (score 2):

If you are a tenant, you would be "renting" an apartment.

If you are a landlord, you would be "letting" an apartment.

Sometimes landlords will use the word "rent." In this case, they need to say that they are renting OUT an apartment. For emphasis, a landlord could say that s/he was "letting out" the apartment.

A tenant could say that s/he was "letting in" an apartment, or letting an apartment from [the landlord]. That's not common.

Because a tenant is renting IN an apartment. That is what is commonly understood by the word "rent."