# What is difference between renter, tenant and rentee?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am a bit confused about the meaning of these three words. Can someone explain to me the usage of these three words and their meaning? i.e. If I am renting a car to someone then who am I and who takes a car on rent?

I found in google search that people are using same meaning for renter and tenant.

Comment: Have you tried to look up a dictionary?

Comment: @Rathony i tried in google but i found different meanings for same words. I want to know exact meaning of these three words.

Comment: Please inlcude what you found in the question so that this question won't be closed.

Comment: *Tenant* has been used in land law since at least the 12th century and relates to *tenements* held with any kind of title from a Lord. It is still the usual term for anyone renting property on a lease. I have never heard it used in connection with car rental. But in Britain we often talk of car hire (rather than rent), where I feel sure the terms *hirer* and *hiree* apply.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can "rentee" be used to refer to one who rents an item?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264419/can-rentee-be-used-to-refer-to-one-who-rents-an-item)

Comment: Most of the responses here are apparently based on British usage.  In the US, "tenant" is the one who pays rent and occupies the space, "renter" is the same (more or less) as "tenant", as is "lessee", and "landlord" (or "lessor") is the person to whom you pay the rent.  "Rentee" is rarely seen, if at all.  The choice of terminology is based to a degree on whether the property is under long-term lease or not.  And there is no doubt some variation in the "preferred" term from one major city to another.

Comment: @HotLicks Your comment appears to be primarily about renting a building or land. The example in the Q. is about renting a car. And which responses do you consider to be "based on British usage"? What difference is there between US & UK usage? Op's name could suggest Asian usage?

Comment: Consulting an ordinary dictionary will give one separate definitions of *renter* and *tenant*, from which one can conclude that they are very close in meaning, but such a dictionary will not explicitly compare them and bring out the differences between them. It is therefore quite reasonable to ask at this site what these differences are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Renter** <sup>[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/renter)</sup>
>
> 1. One that receives payment in exchange for the use of one's property by another.
> 2. One that pays rent for the use of another's property; a tenant.
>
> **Tenant** <sup>[2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tenant)</sup>
>
> 1. One that pays rent to use or occupy land, a building, or other property owned by another.
> 2. A dweller in a place; an occupant.

**Rentee** already has an answer here: [Can "rentee" be used to refer to one who rents an item?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264419/can-rentee-be-used-to-refer-to-one-who-rents-an-item)

Rentee doesn't apply unless what's being rented is a person, in which case the rentee is the person (slave) being rented.

The difference: a tenant or a rentee will never be the owner receiving payment for use. A renter might be.

The two different meanings of the word **renter** can usually be distinguished with the words `to` and `from`:

- If I rent something *to* you, I get paid and you get to use it.
- If I rent something *from* you, I get to use it and you get paid.

Comment: While the everyday meaning of *tenant* is such that it is indeed true that 'a tenant . . . will never be the owner', there is a technical sense that *tenant* has in some legal contexts, in which tenants can be owners.  Most people will never encounter such use of the term, though.

Answer (score 0):

- **renter**

  someone who have some building for rent, e.g. landlord
- **tenant**

  someone who pays the rent for the place they live in(pays money to landlord)
- **rentee**

  eh, I have no idea about this word :)

[*Note: Both two words renter and tenant are most used for building, flat, etc.*]

Comment: The meaning you give for _renter_ is possible, but unlikely. Until I read what you had written it never occurred to me (native English speaker) that that was a possible meaning of _renter_: I would always assume it meant the tenant unless the context strongly overturned that assumption.

Comment: In the US "renter" is taken to mean the person who pays rent to occupy the space.  "Landlord" is the person who owns the property and is paid the rent.

Comment: Lawyers and most leases in the UK (not sure about Scotland) use the words 'leasor' and 'leasee' for the landlord and tenant respectively. Never come across 'renter' in leases. Have only encountered this word in car rental agreements.

Answer (score 0):

A **renter** is a person who pays rent in order to use something that to belongs to someone else, whether it be a house, room or even a car. But a **tenant** can be a renter, free occupier or a caretaker of someone's property eg. House, Room etc.